# Preventing referencing in a proc?

Tags: tcl

I would like to pass to a proc a variable name and use it 
inside the proc.

problem is that passing argument into the proc converts the variable to its value:

```
set my_value [ list eee ttt yyy ]
proc my_proc { args } {
    puts "MY ARGS IS :$args\n"
}

my_proc $my_value
MY ARGS IS :{eee ttt yyy}
```

I would like to get:

```
MY ARGS IS : my_value
```

thanks
Uri

Comment: Perhaps I should rethink about the approach.

I pass to the proc either variable or cmd. I want 
to print their content, for variable with puts for a cmd with eval

set var_global  [list AA BB CC DD ]
set cmd_global  "llength {1 2 3 4 5}"

my_proc $var_global
my_proc $cmd_global

the proc must treat differently the 2 types of args:
proc my_proc { args } { 
   if { its_a_variablel } {
         puts "VAR IS : $rags"
    } else {
 foreach itr [eval $cmd_global ]  { puts "CMD RESULTS:$itr" } 
    }
}

desired output:
my_proc $var_global
> VAR IS : AA BB CC DD 

my_proc $cmd_global
> CMD RESULTS:5

Answer (score 5):

Tcl is *strict* pass-by-value in semantics (it's implementation is pass-by-*immutable*-reference), but the value that you pass can be a name (just don't put `$` in front of it, since to Tcl that *always* means “read from this variable, now”). In particular, you would do just this:

```
my_proc my_value
```

If you wanted to bind that name to a local variable so you can read and write it, you'd then do something like this (inside the procedure):

```
proc my_proc { args } {
    upvar 1 [lindex $args 0] theVar
    puts "MY ARGS IS :$args"
    puts "THE VARIABLE CONTAINS <$theVar>"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking too hard. If you want `my_value` to be passed in, that's exactly what you do:

```
my_proc my_value
```

Tcl is very simple in this regard: if you want the name, use the name, and if you want the value, put a `$` in front of the name.